# Symplectic quasi-states and displaceability of subsets of symplectic manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

In the paper "Quasi-states and symplectic intersections", Entov and Polterovich, introduced the notion of a partial symplectic quasi-state and used it the prove the following theorem:

> Let $(M,\omega)$ be a closed symplectic manifold and $\mathbb{A}$ a finite-dimensional Poisson commutative subspace of $C^{\infty}(M)$. Then, there exists $y_0\in \Phi(M)$ such that $\Phi^{-1}(y_0)$ is non-displaceable from itself.

Furthermore, they introduced the notion of superheavy and heavy subsets associated with symplectic quasi-states.

Now in the paper "Existence of pseudoheavy fibers of moment maps" by Kawasaki and Orita, the authors define the notion of a pseudohevy set with respect to a symplectic quasi-state $\xi$ and prove the following:

> Let $(M,\omega)$ be a closed symplectic manifold and $\mathbb{A}$ a finite-dimensional Poisson commutative subspace of $C^{\infty}(M)$. Then, there exists $y_0\in \Phi(M)$ such that $\Phi^{-1}(y_0)$ is $\zeta-$pseudoheavy.

Now my question is suppose that we have a closed symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ and $\mathbb{A}$ a finite-dimensional Poisson subspace and $y_0$ such that $\Phi^{-1}(y_0)$ is non-displaceable. Does there exist a partial symplectic quasi-state $\zeta$, such that $\Phi^{-1}(y_0)$ is pseudoheavy with respect to this $\zeta$? Or is the notion of non-displaceability weaker than being pseudoheasvy ?

Any insight is appreciated.